# How to check several local variables for the same if conditions

Tags: javascript

Alright, I find the code below to be quite repetitive and annoying. Any other way to refactor the code without using an array as a starting point (that is, to avoid using `array[x]`, `array[y]`, `array[z]` later on in the code as a result of starting with an array because `x`,`y`,`z` are completely unrelated and it makes no sense to group them for the sake of readability)

```
var x = "";
var y = "";
var z = "";
...

...variables get set

if(x != undefined && x != "")
    doSomethingHere();

if(y != undefined && y != "")
    doSomethingThere();

if(z != undefined && z != "")
    doSomethingElse();
...
```

Comment: Is it exactly the same "doSomething()" that you call for each variable or should the definition of each variable trigger a different function call?

Comment: it may be different, thanks for your interest (I know my sample is not great)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what joel said you could also do the following:

```
function doOnValid(x, func){
 if(x != undefined && x != "") func();
}
```

Then you could do:

```
doOnValid(x, doSomething);
doOnValid(y, doSomethingElse);
doOnvalid(z, function() { /*Yay lambda function*/ });
```

Comment: you forgot to change the x in the function to var. ;)

Comment: Whoops. should of read down a bit more before suggesting this on Joel's.

Comment: You should probably change the name of "isValid" to something else, it's not returning a bool.

Comment: Your right, I copied Joels function and edited it. I'll rename to: DoOnValid() (I'm not very good at function naming.)

Answer (score 8):

At very least you can factor out your validation rules to their own function:

```
function IsValid(x)
{
    return (x != undefined && x != "");
}

var x = "";
var y = "";
var z = "";
//...

//...variables get set

if(IsValid(x)) doSomething();
if(IsValid(y)) doSomething();
if(IsValid(z)) doSomething();
```

Comment: Take that one step more and let the IsValid accept a func and do the "if" check in there. 

IfIsValid(x,doSomethingHere);
IfIsValid(y,doSomethingThere);

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to avoid repetition, be it vertical (var x;\r\n;var y;\r\n...) or horizontal (if (x || y || z || ...), a nice way to tidy things up is to gather your variables into an object as properties:

```
var vars = {
    x: 42,
    y: "",
    z: undefined
};

for (var v in vars) {
    var value = vars[v];

    if (value != undefined && value != "") {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

On top of that, if the action to be taken is different for each variable, you can also define an "actions" structure:

```
var actions = {
    x: doSomething,
    y: doSomethingElse,
    z: doSomething
};

for (var v in vars) {
    var value = vars[v];

    if (value != undefined && value != "") {
        actions[v]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you initialize x,y and z to "" ?

If you just do

```
 var x;

 ..... maybe set x .....

 if (x)
    doSomething()
```

You save quite a lot of fuzz. You can do the same for y and z ;) The initial value of x is undefined, which you can check with if (x), which means the same as if (x != undefined)

Comment: Actually, in javascript any of the following values will evaluate as false in a conditional:  false, null, undefined, "", 0, NAN.

Comment: .... and therefore (adding to what JacobM said) the statement you wrote is not equivalent to the one  in the question

Comment: @Newbie you're right. I still think you should rework the intermediate setting logic so that my code becomes your code ;) There's something about the "rule of least-surprise" which I feel you're violating.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, because both undefined and the empty string ("") evaluate as "false" in javascript, you can change your conditionals to:

```
if (x) 
     doSomething();
if (y) 
     doSomething();
if (z) 
     doSomething();
```

If the Something to be Done is always the same, you can certainly do

```
if (x || Y || z)
     doSomething();
```

Comment: but if x,y,z, equal to 0 then you example wont work, it will not give the same results as the example provided in the question

Comment: Fair point.  We're assuming a particular type of value (which of course we can't be guaranteed in Javascript).  We assume all of the values are strings; it will work properly if assigned to "0", just not to 0.

Comment: Similarly, your original code would ignore Null or NaN, which might not be what you want.

Comment: You are 100% right. I think Joel Coehoorn's, below, solution is the best fit for the problem. Do you agree?

Comment: It depends.  The cleanest solution might be to try to match up your particular needs with the way javascript defines "truthiness" -- but that might not be possible.  If the conditional is complicated or likely to change, than abstracting it into a boolean function is definitely a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the original should have used y != undefined and doSomething () is the same function in all cases:

```
if((x != undefined && x != "") || 
   (y != undefined && y != "") ||
   (z != undefined && z != ""))
    doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

So to follow up on krosenvold's answer I think what you want is

```
var x;
var y;
var z;

// do stuff

if (x||y||z)
  doSomething();
```

Which is much neater

Comment: what you wrote is very different from the example in the question, for example, what if x, y, or z  are equal to 0? Then your if returns false

Answer (score 0):

This is about as concise as I can make it, assuming you want a unique action for each condition.

```
(x && doX());
(y && doY());
(z && doZ());
```

This works because your particular variable test just reduces to the value of the variable.  You can, of course, also write a custom condition function:

```
function is_valid(x){
    // return true or false
}

( is_valid(x) && doX() );
( is_valid(y) && doY() );
( is_valid(z) && doZ() );
```